# Pass a function arguments?

Tags: shell, function, arguments

How would you make a function that gets arguments?

```
function arg_example {
    arg "c"  # This is imaginary but it would return 'true' if it found the argument -c.
    did_find_arg=$?  # Get the previous function (arg)'s output.

    if [$did_find_arg == 'true']; then
        echo "Yes!"
    else
        echo "Not found."
    fi
}

# Testing
arg_example  # "Not found."
arg_example -c  # "Yes!"
arg_example -k  # "Not found."
```

Also, how would you find the value of a key-value function, eg `--name`:

```
function hello {
    echo "Hello, $--name!"
}
```

EDIT: I know how to use `$1` and `$2`, but I'd like to know how to get optional things like `-v` or `--version`.

Comment: That's where you want to use `getopts` (remember to reset OPTIND and/or make is local for shells that support local scope)

Comment: Take a look at [getopts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts)

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: Don't forget that you need to have spaces around `[` and `]` in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Processing the command line of a *function* may be done with `getopts` in exactly the same way as processing the command line for a *script*.  The only thing to watch out for is that `OPTIND` will have to be reset to 1 or made local to the function:

```
#!/bin/bash

myfunc () {
    local OPTIND
    local do_c=0
    local do_k=0
    local opt

    while getopts 'ck' opt; do
        case $opt in
            c) do_c=1 ;;
            k) do_k=1 ;;
            *) echo 'Error in command line parsing' >&2
               return 1
        esac
    done
    shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

    if [ "$do_c" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo 'Yes!'
    else
        echo 'Not found'
    fi
}

myfunc
myfunc -c
myfunc -k
myfunc -a
```

The above script produces:

```
Not found
Yes!
Not found
script.sh: illegal option -- a
Error in command line parsing
```

Related:

- [bash function arguments strange behaviour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436454)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple named argument extractor for Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

getargs()
{
  local out=""
  for argname in "$@"; do
    out="${out}local $argname=\$1; shift;"
  done
  printf "%s" "$out"
}

testfun()
{
  eval $(getargs a b c)
  printf "a = %s, b = %s, c = %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"
}

testfun "$@"
```

Since we want the arguments to be local variables in the dynamic scope of the function `testfun`, `getargs` cannot be a function call. Rather, `getargs` is a tiny **compiler** which translates an argument specification like `a b c` into shell **syntax**, generating the code which we would otherwise manually add in order to get the positional argument into local variables.

For instance, the output of

```
getargs a b c
```

is the source code:

```
local a=$1; shift;local b=$1; shift;local c=$1; shift
```

when we `eval` that, it does what it looks like it does. In the context of the caller, it gets the first three positional arguments into `a`, `b` and `c`, shifting them out of the argument list.

Now we could take this to the next level and add "bells and whistles".

For starters, the generated code could **check** that there actually are exactly three arguments and diagnose.

We could support optional arguments: `getargs a b : c` (or whatever) could mean that `a` and `b` are required, but `c` is optional. We could also support trailing arguments: `getargs a b : c . d` could generate code which gets the first two arguments (which are required) into locals `a` and `b`. Then if a third argument is present, it goes into `c`. Any arguments after that go into `d`, which is a Bash array.

I will leave that as an exercise.

Too bad that the shell doesn't have a macro-expansion time. The big downside of this is that the code is generated each time the function is called, even though it is completely static.

You could write some sort of preprocessor (e.g. in Awk) to transform some sort of named function syntactic sugar into regular shell code.