# bash function arguments strange behaviour

Tags: bash, function, arguments, getopts

I have the following bash function:

```
lscf() {
  while getopts f:d: opt ; do
    case $opt in
      f) file="$OPTARG" ;;
      d) days="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
  done

  echo file is $file
  echo days is $days
}
```

Running this with arguments does not output any values. Only after running the function without arguments, and then again with arguments does it output the correct values:

```
-bash-4.1$ lscf -d 10 -f file.txt
file is
days is

-bash-4.1$ lscf
file is
days is

-bash-4.1$ lscf -d 10 -f file.txt
file is file.txt
days is 10
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `local OPTIND` at the first of your function

Comment: thanks @cuonglm, that solved it. Would you mind explaining why this worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I can't reproduce the initial run of the function that you have in your question, you should reset `OPTIND` to 1 in your function to be able to process the function's command line in repeated invocations of it.

From the `bash` manual:

> `OPTIND` is initialized to
>                 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.  When an
>                 option requires an argument, `getopts` places that argument into
>                 the variable `OPTARG`.  **The shell does not reset `OPTIND`
>                 automatically; it must be manually reset between multiple calls
>                 to `getopts` within the same shell invocation if a new set of
>                 parameters is to be used.**

From [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/getopts.html):

> If the application sets `OPTIND` to the value 1, a new set of parameters can be used: either the current positional parameters or new arg values. **Any other attempt to invoke `getopts` multiple times in a single shell execution environment with parameters (positional parameters or arg operands) that are not the same in all invocations, or with an `OPTIND` value modified to be a value other than 1, produces unspecified results.**

The "shell invocation" that the `bash` manual mentions is the same as the "single execution environment" that the POSIX text mentions, and both refer to your shell script or interactive shell.  Within the script or interactive shell, multiple calls to your `lscf` will invoke `getopts` in the same environment, and `OPTIND` will need to be reset to 1 before each such invocation.

Therefore:

```
lscf() {
  OPTIND=1

  while getopts f:d: opt ; do
    case $opt in
      f) file="$OPTARG" ;;
      d) days="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
  done

  echo file is $file
  echo days is $days
}
```

If the variables `file` and `days` should *not* be set in the calling shell's environment, they should be local variables. Also, quote variable expansions and use `printf` to output variable data:

```
lscf() {
  local file
  local days

  OPTIND=1

  while getopts f:d: opt ; do
    case $opt in
      f) file="$OPTARG" ;;
      d) days="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
  done

  printf 'file is %s\n' "$file"
  printf 'days is %s\n' "$days"
}
```